# How do I get the URI of the images shown in recent folder in Gallery?

Tags: java, android, file, media

I wanted to get the Image URIs of the images, as well as that of the videos in the "Recent" folder in gallery and store them in an ArrayList.

Normally, for example, if I want to access the Pictures folder, Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); gives the URI to the pictures folder, similar is for the movies folder. But no idea about how to do that for the "Recent" folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not much, I know to get the URI to the Pictures directory or Movies directory. But no idea about the "Recent" folder.

Comment: Ok please include the information on how to do Pictures or Movies directories, but do so *in the question* as an edit, not in a comment.

Comment: Fine, included it.

Comment: you have to use cursors and read the latest file

Comment: And how do I do that ?